# Update .m3u8 playlist while live streaming

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, streaming, rtmp, m3u8

Im using nginx-rtmp-module to create a RTMP server and I'm using hls directives to create the playlist.

```
hls on;
hls_path /var/www/html/cam/;
hls_fragment 10;
hls_nested on;
hls_playlist_length 7d;
hls_cleanup off;
hls_continuous on;
hls_fragment_naming system;
```

Now, **I want to update manually the .m3u8 playlist file** from this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:12
#EXTINF:10.000,
1658833177814.ts
#EXTINF:10.000,
1658833187826.ts
#EXTINF:10.000,
1658833197826.ts
```

to this, **when the streaming is "on line"**:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3  
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:12
#EXTINF:10.000,
1658833197826.ts
```

if I do it when there is no live streaming, that works, but if i do it when there is a live streaming, the .m3u8 file becames as the original after the server finish the creation of the last chunk. Even if i delete the .m3u8 file, it is recreated as the original one.

I've also tryed it using ffmpeg instead of hls directives without success, and looked [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58454766/videojs-how-to-update-m3u8-playlist-dynamically) but